# Best way to render and update an image each frame?

Tags: java, lwjgl

What is the best way to edit singular pixels of an texture multiple times per frame? I have tried using a couple ways to no avail. What is the most optimal way to do this? I have tried using Intermediate mode and drawing each quad, thought, this is really slow.

Edit:
I forgot to mention that I am doing an unusual "fog of war" system. This system doesn't let you see around walls but instead acts like a 2D ray traced shadow. I want these shadows to be pixelated as this is part of the style of the game. I am trying to find the best way to do a form of a shadow map that I can overlay over the world to show what you can see.

Comment: Please be more specific or give examples. It's very difficult to answer a generic question like this. Based on your question, intuitively, you could just change all the pixels you want and then do a single redraw, but that could be just because your question isn't clear.

Comment: Also put some snippets that you tried?

Comment: Editing pixels of a texture is expensive. Why are you doing it, and is there any way you can avoid doing it?

Comment: @thedaian I edited the question to answer some questions.

Comment: @jzila Basically, What is the best way to do a 2D shadow map that changes each frame as the player moves?

Comment: Can you post an image of what the output it supposed to look like (slow or not)? What you want the composite image to look like may affect the technique that is recommended.

Comment: I believe that the OpenGL superbible has a shadowmap example. Maybe you could use a modified version of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a [Pixel Buffer Object](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html).